# Attaching an e-mail form to a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I would like to change the below link into an form that posts params of the form to my controller to send an email... the current link works and sends an email...

```
<%= button_to 'Hello', contact_pages_path, :method => :put %>
```

In My controller I have:

```
 def contact
   Contact.contact_form.deliver
 end
```

My Mailer:

```
class Contact < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "****"
  default to: "****"

  def contact_form
    mail(:subject => "Registered")
  end


end
```

and in my routes I have:

```
  resources :pages do
  put :contact, :on => :collection
  end
```

I realise that I need to create a body in the mailer - but I am not sure how to create a form to do this and pass it all on. I did think about creating a model to do this, but I thought having an entire model for just sending an email from a form would be slight over kill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= form_tag(contact_pages_path, :method => "post") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag "article", "firstname" %> 
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end -%>
```

When you submit it will go to `contact_pages_path` and in your controller try `params[:article]`, so its value should be "first name".

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom forms using `form_tag` and then use a `text_area_tag` to take in the body. As long as you give it a name, it will be sent in the params. Example (using HAML):

```
= form_tag contact_pages_path, :method => :put
    = text_area_tag "body"
    = submit_tag "Send"
```

And then in your controller you can access the text in the body with `params[:body]`.

Look [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_area_tag) for more information about the `text_area_tag` (takes in many options you may want to use) and you can also read up more on the `form_tag`.

This also doesn't require you to make an extra model.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**In erb file**

```
<%= form_tag(contact_pages_path, :method => "post") do %>
  From : <%= text_field_tag "from_email", "" %> <br/>
  To : <%= text_field_tag "to_email", "" %> <br/>
  Message:<br/>
  <%= = text_area_tag "message" %>
  <%= submit_tag "send" %>
<% end %>
```

**in action**

```
def contact
 from_email = params[:from_email]
 to_email = params[:to_email]
 message = params[:message]

 // do operation to send the mail
end
```