# Action after form Submission on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a working form that posts to a controller to send an email.

Controller:

```
 def contact
    name = params[:contact][:your_name]
    message = params[:contact][:your_message]
    email = params[:contact ][:your_email]
    Contact.contact_form(message, name, email).deliver
    redirect_to :back
 end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for :contact , :url => contact_pages_path(@message), :html => {:method => :put} do |f| %>
<p>
<b>Your email:</b><br>
<%= f.text_field :your_email %>
<b>Name</b><br>
<%= f.text_field :your_name %>
</p>
<p>
<b>Message</b><br>
<%= f.text_area :your_message %>
 </p>
<p>
```

However I am not very happy with the

```
redirect_to :back
```

As it just reloads the page. How can I flash a message up afterwards saying "Thankyou" without moving away from the page? The message could even appear in the form - so afterwards a box appears saying - "Thanks"

Comment: you have just asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926992/attaching-an-e-mail-form-to-a-controller/8927840#8927840 , you should not create another question, you can update same question with full details to get a better and detailed answer.

Comment: I was under the impression that when the qustion changed you added a new question

Answer (score 1):

```
redirect_to :back, :notice => "Thank-you"
```

Of course, this will only work if your `application.html.erb` template is printing out the contents of notices/alerts.  For that, you need something like:

```
    <% if !notice.nil? || !alert.nil? %>
        <section id="message" class="message-<%= notice.nil? ? "alert" : "notice" %>">
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <% if !notice.nil? %>
                        <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
                    <% end %>
                    <% if !alert.nil? %>
                        <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks - but I get no message appearing??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but could you please try this?

```
if Contact.contact_form(message, name, email).deliver
  flash[:notice] = "mail has been sent successfully."
```

I think you may be don't have to redirect to anywhere. 
Hope it will help.

Comment: I will find for other solution then

Comment: what about render :nothing => true

Comment: flash.now[:notice] = 'mail has been sent successfully.' This should not reload the page.

Comment: http://www.pluitsolutions.com/2006/07/28/rails-using-flashnotice-without-redirect/  I think this link will be helpful for you I think you have to render after that. I will research more about it.

Comment: render :layout => "your contact layout"